# How to move Database Diagram from One Server to Another Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, database-diagram

I have created a new Database Diagram in Test Database and it is in sitde01 Server. Now I want to move it to another server. How do I migrate it to another server.

Comment: a diagram is only a visual view of all PK and FK ... you can easily create a script to update an existing db with this info.

Comment: @balexandre - Not true at all.  In a diagram you can have text annotations.  Also, the graphical layout of the tables in the diagram can convey how tables are logically grouped together.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can be done, but it's a royal pain. Here's an outline of the process and some scripts.

Diagrams are stored in a "system" table named sysDiagrams. This table (only?) gets created when you click on the diagrams node in SSMS, it asks you if you want to create the objects that support diagrams, and you click "Yes". Do so on both your source and target databases.

Create the diagram or diagrams in the "source" database.

Review the structure and contents of sysDiagrams. Note that column `diagram_id` is an identity column. 1 row gets stored for every diagram. (You don't care, but it used to be 4 or 5 rows in SQL 2000.)

To copy to another database *on the same SQL instance*, the simplest way is to do INSERT... SELECT... between tables. With that identity column in the way, you'll have to fuss with SET IDENTITY_INSERT, and perhaps assign a new identity value on the target computer. Irritating, but not critically hard.

The following script will copy all diagrams from one database to another that's on the same server (this is how I archive complex diagrams that took waaaay too long to create, from databases that are prone to get dropped and recreated):

```
USE TargetDatabase

DELETE sysDiagrams
 where name in (select name from SourceDatabase.dbo.sysDiagrams)

SET identity_insert sysDiagrams on

INSERT sysDiagrams (name, principal_id, diagram_id, version, definition)
 select name, principal_id, diagram_id, version, definition
  from SourceDatabase.dbo.sysDiagrams

SET identity_insert sysDiagrams off
```

To copy to another database *on a different SQL instance (or server),* well, it gets even harder. I use temporarily created Linked Server definitions, using scripts I sweated bullets over years ago and never want to have to modify again (i.e. post a different question so someone who knows can tell you how they work), and modify the scripts with appropriate four-part naming conventions. Other options (OPENROWSET and the like) are possible, but I'm even less familiar with those.

Comment: +1: This worked for me. It wasn't really a big deal since I was on the same server, but until I found this script I struggled a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move your diagrams from one instance or server to a different one, and you don't want to restore the whole database, you can do the following.

1. If it doesn't exist, create the database on your target server. You also have to click on the "Database Diagrams" node in SSMS to have it create a dbo.sysDiagrams table.
2. Then make sure to import all the schema information you need in your diagram. Because your diagram will point to these. I.e. tables, PK, FK etc. must be present.
3. Backup your database on the source server.
4. Restore it into a temporary database on the target server. In this way you get all your diagram information into the target server.
5. Copy the information from the dbo.sysDiagrams table in the temporary database into the dbo.sysDiagram table of your target database. You could do something like this (adapted the code from Philip Kelley):

   ```
   USE TargetDatabase 

   SET identity_insert sysDiagrams on 

   INSERT sysDiagrams (name, principal_id, diagram_id, version, definition) 
    select name, principal_id, diagram_id, version, definition 
     from TempDatabase.dbo.sysDiagrams 

   SET identity_insert sysDiagrams off
   ```

This solution worked excelent for me. Of course if you don't want all the diagrams or if other diagrams are existing in the target database, you have to filter the select statement and do some identity_insert manipulation, but this shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move the database-diagram you will need to migrate all the tables and triggers included in that diagram.  The easiest way to do this is backup the db and restore on the other server.

Comment: backup and restore is the only way i know you can migrate a diagram.

Comment: I dont want to do backup and restore since the tables are not same in bith the servers. Is there a way other than backup and restore?